# when to use Thread, interrupt and join

Tags: java, multithreading

i am doing a sleeping barber prob. So, first i create 10 customer threads with 2 sec "sleep" between each other. now, the first client gets hair cut, means sleeping 5 sec.. we have waiting room for following threads where we have place for only 3 threads.

if a customer thread is getting hair cut, and 3 following threads are in queue, other customer threads created after that must stop unless there is an available position in 3 sit waiting room.

when 1st customer gets cut, second customers cut starts,, so 2 threads are in queue, only in this case one more thread can join the waiting.

to do all these task, can someone tell me in short, where to use sleep, interrupt and join. especially how to make threads wait for others to finish, and how to detect how many threads are currently waiting/sleeping?

Comment: Are you allowed to use higher level apis like ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: What have you tried?  What code have you written?  Have you tried to debug it?  StackOverflow is not a research assistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additiv [semaphores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with 3 places for the waiting room and one binary semaphore for the barber.

```
Semaphore waitingRoom = new Semaphore(3);
Semaphore barber= new Semaphore(1);
```

The method cut shoud be like this:

```
waitingRoom.acquire();

barber.acquire();
waitingRoom.release()

Thread.sleep(300)

barber.release()
```

You use `.join()` only if you waiting for a thread to continue your programm. You don't need to interrupt this thread, it must just finish his `run()`.

`.interrupt()` will hold on the thread.

Answer (score 1):

sleep() method delays the execution of a thread by specified period of time. While sleeping, the thread does not release its lock. It still holds it.

If a thread calls join method on another thread, then it means that the thread will become runnable only after another has completed running. e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread thread1 = new Thread();
    thread1.join();
}
```

Above code means that the main thread will become runnable after the thread1 has completed running.
If you use overloaded version of join method.

```
thread1.join(100)
```

This will mean that wait for 100 milliseconds for the thread1 to complete, but if that doesn't happen, become runnable anyone. So main thread will become runnable even if thread1 does not complete in 100 milliseconds